# How to prevent Spring JPA Entities from becoming optional when saving to CRUDRepository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I was trying to learn Spring Framework and ran into a problem with saving entities into CRUD Repository. I had few Entities with automatic numeric ID generation and they work just fine, but then I tried to make a class with String being a primary key just like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
@Builder
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_NAME", nullable = false)
    @Getter @Setter
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "USER_PASS", nullable = false)
    @Getter @Setter
    private String pass;
}
```

First I was getting exceptions about this class not having a default constructor:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.company.Model.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.company.Model.User
```

Already weird, but still I decided to change @Builder annotation into 2 constructors, one with both arguments and second with none. I tried to save the entity instance into CRUD Repository userDAO (which is nothing more than interface extending CRUDRepository) by the typical test:

```
User admin = new User("admin", "6aDcZ72k");

...

@Test
public void saveUserAndFindById() {
    admin = userDAO.save(admin);
    assertThat(userDAO.findById(admin.getName())).isEqualTo(admin);
}
```

The result was assertion failed because the saved entity had "Optional" type:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :com.company.Model.User@2c06b113
Actual   :Optional[com.company.Model.User@2c06b113]
```

I know I'm doing something really wrong but can't figure this out. Or maybe there is a way to just prevent making it optional? There must be few other entities with the reference on this class, but these references obviously don't work because of the above issue.

Comment: Try this assertThat(userDAO.findById(admin.getName()).getPassword()).isEqualTo(admin.getPassword());

Comment: To start with, aside from the 2 constructors you've added, also include a default constructor in your entity (without args)

Comment: @PoojaAggarwal Yeah, it'll pass, but still an attempt to make a reference on User from another entity will throw TransientPropertyValueException telling me that User is transcient/optional and that is not really meant to be.

Comment: @geneqew Like I said, the second constructor is already without any args. It just don't work without default constructor

Comment: Well, yes, findById() returns an Optional<User>. That would be clear if you read the javadoc. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findById-ID-. Here's the javadoc of Optional to learn how to use it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Comment: After including no args constructor, update your test. Spring Data's Repository's findById returns Optional type while save returns your User as type. In order to test this properly, invoke optional's get method if you want to assert that it matches what you've saved

Comment: For more info, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,**jpa require the entity has a No Arguments Constructor** cause it will create a instance first and then populate it.The easiest way is to add @NoArgumentsConstructor that offered by lombok on the entity class.

And then,Optional is used by spring data jpa in order to avoid NullPointException and in fact it be is useful actually.If you want to use the interface that Spring-data-jpa offered,then you have to use Optional too.You cloud look here for more info about Optional:[link1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html),[link2](https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional)

By the way,I usually use it like:

```
ExampleEntity example=exampleRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(()->new ExampleNotFoundException());
```

In this way,you dont need to deal with Optional or think about NullPointException.

or:

```
ExampleEntity example=exampleRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
```

In this way if you cant find the target entity,then it will be null.So dont forget to check if the entity is null.

Hope it could help~~~

Answer (score 1):

It is not your `save(...)` that is returning `Optional` but `userDAO.findById(admin.getName()`. According to the documentation, `CrudReposiotry` provides a `findById()` whose return type is `Optional<T>`.

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
  extends Repository<T, ID> {
    Optional<T> findById(ID primaryKey);
}
```

If you do not want `Optional` as return type, You will need to provide your own method to do that. For example:

```
public interface PeronRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {
    Person findById(String personId);
}
```